# Pointer to a BitmapImage in a class

Tags: c#, class, pointers, bitmapimage

I'm creating a class, Plants. There will be many objects created from this class. Each object will need to contain a BitmapImage of the Plant.

However, there are only about 20 different kinds of Plants. Rather than thousands of objects each containing a BitmapImage, is it possible to have a pointer back to one of the different plant BitmapImages? I'm thinking this would save a LOT of memory.

First: is this a good idea?
Second, how would I implement this?

Comment: Sounds like implementing the *Flyweight design pattern* may be useful here.  Check out: http://www.oodesign.com/flyweight-pattern.html

Comment: Thanks for the link; I may implement something like this elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, outside of the unsafe context there are no pointers in C#. Here's a suggestion on how to do it.

Load your 20 different Plant images in a dictionary. Make it a static property in the Plant class. In each instance have a `string[] keys` property. This is an array with keys for the images that instance should display (or just make it a single string if they're limited to one image). When an instance needs to display it's image retrieve it from the class with `BitmapImage toDisplay = Plant.Images[myInstance.keys[0]]` or something to that effect.

This allows you to store very plant image only once at the class level. Since all instances share the same images library it makes since to have it as a static property on the class itself. If an instance needs it's image it gets if from the classes image library. It only stores the keys of which images it should display. This gives you a similar memory profile to the "each instance has a pointer to the singleton of the image it will display" but in a way that is more aligned with C#.

Comment: This is a really nice solution. Each Plant will have 3 pointers - sorry, references - to 3 different BitmapImage (young, medium, adult). At runtime it will fetch the correct image and display.

Comment: Is there an advantage to using a dictionary over an array BitmapImage PlantPix[20,3] for example? Or would every instantiation of a Plant object automatically grab all 60 bitmaps?

Comment: Ah you would do; `dictionary<string, BitmapImage>` where the key is a string and the value is a bitmap image. The dictionary is just a way to group all of the Bitmaps.

Answer (score 2):

It is not only a good Idea, it's [best practice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern). Since you're using C#, though, use references instead of pointers, ok?

Create a class that has a private instance of the [Bitmap class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx). Give the class a public property with a `get` acessor to return that private instance.

Now, whomever needs to use that instance, can simply reference the property you created. You can serve it through an instance of the holding class, or you can make things static, your choice.

Remember that you'll need one instance of `Bitmap` for every image (you may then use a data structure like a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) to group them), and that if you make a change to a bitmap, it's going to affect everybody using it.

Comment: Is there an advantage to using a dictionary over an array BitmapImage PlantPix[20,3] for example? Or would every instantiation of a Plant object automatically grab all 60 bitmaps?

Comment: A Dictionary will allow you to retrieve a given bitmap through an arbitrary key, set by you. It's just more flexible than accessing through a couple of indexes, but other than that there isn't much mroe advantage. An example of retrieving from a Dictionary: `Bitmap b = PlantPix.Dictionary["adult aloe"];` (compare with `Bitmap b = PlantPix.arrayOfPlants[10, 1];`, for example).

Comment: Just took a break and went to the store and had an epiphany. I can see the power of a Dictionary because I assume I can concatenate the string that will be used as a key. So Plants.Name + Plants.Age (Aloe Adult) can be used as the key to the bitmap. Very nice. Thanks!